# Msgpack on Cloudant

Tags: cloudant, msgpack

I am trying to use msgpack with Cloudant, and I couldn't find any documentation on it.

2 years ago, Tim Anglade [present msgpack as a wonderfull way to pack your data instead of JSON](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=zEMfvCqVL4E#t=887). 
I was thinking that now it was stable to post some msgpack data out of the box ([like the Tim fork of couchDB seems to do](https://github.com/timanglade/couchdb/commit/b601286dae04bdc2488a0d9bf028c58e6feb3449)).

Here my try in python:

```
 import requests, msgpack
 requests.post("https://me.cloudant.com/mydb",
        data=msgpack.packb({ "type"="Test", "ok" : True }),
        auth=(username, password),
        headers={
            "Content-Type" : "application/x-msgpack"
        })
```

I get an `Unsupported Media Type, Content-Type must be application/json`response...

Do you have any solutions, or suggestion for compressing my data ? We are pushing a huge amount of data from a mobile app, and we really need to stay small.

Comment: What's your goal here - is is compression of data on the wire or to save disk space in Cloudant? The former could be done using gzip compressed request bodies.

Comment: My goal is to send compressed data from client to Cloudant, in order to minimize size of POST request, as we are limited by a 64MB by post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, 
I get a response from Cloudant, it's simply not possible to use MsgPack to transfert my datas.

> It looks like 'Content-Type:application/msgpack' is not supported by
>   Cloudant and there is no development work currently being done to do
>   so. Sorry for any inconvenience this may cause.

It looks like there is no way of encoding data in a more efficient way than JSON, that sad.